# Add grand total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't seem to figure out here is how to add that grand total line. I tried rollup and group sets but it just doubled the cumsum and the sumprice which I don't want.

This is what I need to mimick:

[image: This is what I need to mimick]

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(s.OrderDate) AS Year,
    MONTH(s.OrderDate) AS Month,
    SUM(sd.UnitPrice) AS Sum_Price,
    SUM(SUM(sd.UnitPrice)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY MONTH(OrderDate)) AS CumSum
FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader s ON s.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY
    YEAR(s.OrderDate), MONTH(s.OrderDate)
ORDER BY
    Year, Month;
```

I am using AdventureWorks2019

Comment: It would be much better to include the sample results as **formatted text** instead of a screen capture.

Comment: One way is to `UNION` another query for the grand total rows. You can also look into `GROUP BY ROLLUP` to see if that works for you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the issue is this is how the sample results were given to me

Comment: @Isolated group by roll up duplicates the sum_price and the cumsum value as well, i just need to have a grand total row with NULL in the month after the end of a year and before the beginning of the next year

Comment: If the results were given to you like that, there is nothing stopping you making the effort to format them properly for this site. You should also provide a [mre] in the form of DDL+DML so that we can copy and paste and test.

Comment: Normally however you produce your grand totals in your presentation layer, not your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this. The `GROUPING` function will tell you if a column has been grouped up in that row. It returns `0` for a non-aggregated row, and `1` for a rollup.

```sql
SELECT
    YEAR(s.OrderDate) AS Year,
    IIF(GROUPING(MONTH(s.OrderDate)) = 0,
        CAST(MONTH(s.OrderDate) AS varchar(20)),
        'grand_total'
    ) AS Month,
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(MONTH(s.OrderDate) = 0 THEN SUM(sd.UnitPrice) END AS Sum_Price,
    SUM(SUM(sd.UnitPrice)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate), GROUPING(Month)
        ORDER BY MONTH(OrderDate) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumSum
FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader s ON s.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (YEAR(s.OrderDate), MONTH(s.OrderDate)),
    (YEAR(s.OrderDate)
)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(s.OrderDate),
    GROUPING(Month),
    MONTH(s.OrderDate);
```

You can also use a partial `ROLLUP`, although it's less clear what's going on. It compiles to the same thing, so efficiency will be the same. You can still use `GROUPING()` with this method.

```sql
GROUP BY
    YEAR(s.OrderDate),
    ROLLUP(MONTH(s.OrderDate))
```

Comment: This was it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this often so this might be off (I tend to let the client code or reporting tool handle the summaries), but try `ROLLUP` like this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(s.OrderDate) AS Year,
    MONTH(s.OrderDate) AS Month,
    SUM(sd.UnitPrice) AS Sum_Price,
    SUM(SUM(sd.UnitPrice)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(OrderDate) ORDER BY MONTH(OrderDate)) AS CumSum
FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader s ON s.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(MONTH(s.OrderDate)), YEAR(s.OrderDate)
ORDER BY
    Year, Month;
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, unfortunately it doesn't produce the result I need because it also doubles up the CumSum and the SumPrice. I think the grand total row about is meant to be a blank row since I can't see it doing anything to the numbers